# Locking the file while writing in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a requirement where one process continuously writes to the files in a particular folder. At the same time an another script moves the files from that folder to another folder. But files must not be moved while the first process is in the middle of writing to them. Is there any process/function in PowerShell which can fulfill this requirement?

Comment: look into `system.io.filestream.lock()`  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.lock%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 17):

In Powershell the syntax is like this:

```
$path = "C:\file.txt"
$mode = "Open"
$access = "Read"
$share = "None"

$file = [System.IO.File]::Open($path, $mode, $access, $share)
$file.close()
```

---

There is more information available on this Class at the following URL:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y973b725(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks Vasili, As I am new to powershell can you please help more by little elaborate your syntax. Also we don't know the exact file name. It just new files are continuously coming to a folder and we don't want those files to be moved before there writing got finished or not fully received.