# Remove-Item (and [System.IO.File]::Delete() ) removes file that is in use

Tags: powershell, delete-file, file-in-use

I am working on a script to do some cleanup of the many GB of cruft an Autodesk install leaves behind, and I am getting an error about some log file buried deep in the folder structure that is still in use. So, I want to get `$_.exception.GetType().fullname` so I can have a `do/while` loop that loops as long as that is the failure. Or more likely loops until success or a specified number of tries fails.
To that end I created an RTF file on my C drive, opened it in Wordpad and tried this code to get the exception info.

```
$path = 'C:\New folder\New Rich Text Document.rtf'
try {
    Remove-Item $path -errorAction Stop
} catch {
    Write-Host "$($_.exception.GetType().fullname)"
    Write-Host "$($_.exception.message)"
}
```

Net result, without the -Force flag, the file was deleted even while open. Which I THINK really should not happen. Is this just something stupid like Microsoft never bothered to implement file locking with WordPad? Or is there some good reason for this behavior I don't understand? And more importantly, IS there a way to trigger this condition, so that I can actually write and test some code that responds gracefully? Ideally not using MS Office or the like, since I don't have it. Something included with the OS would be ideal.
I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21086051/locking-the-file-while-writing-in-powershell) approach to doing it with PowerShell, so I could have a second script running that locks the file and loops for a time before releasing it, and as long as that time is less than my timeout on the delete it would work. But it seems like I should be able to, just open the file. Though it now occurs to me that the file causing the problem is a log file, so it is likely locked through a mechanism more like that link, rather than actually being "open". But it still seems to me that an open file should be delete-able.

Also, as noted in the title, I tried `[System.IO.File]::Delete($path)` as well, and to my surprise that deletes also. Curiouser and curiouser.

Comment: Looks like Wordpad doesn't lock the file when opening it, unlike Word which should get you the exception you seek.

Comment: @Theo How did you verify that? Is there a way to see WHAT has a file lock? I figured perhaps the free tools from Microsoft are just half finished, and I might need MS Office, which will not be happening. So I used the separate script approach. But would be great to understand how to verify WHAT has a lock, which is I am guessing what you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some applications do not put a lock on a file when opened like for a text file MS Word does. Wordpad however does not, so it is possible to delete the file while it is opened in Wordpad..

To test a file lock, I use a small helper funtion:

```
function Test-LockedFile {
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [Alias('FullName', 'FilePath')]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType Leaf})]
        [string]$Path
    )
    $file = [System.IO.FileInfo]::new($Path)
    # old PowerShell versions use:
    # $file = New-Object System.IO.FileInfo $Path

    try {
        $stream = $file.Open([System.IO.FileMode]::OpenOrCreate,
                             [System.IO.FileAccess]::Write,
                             [System.IO.FileShare]::Delete)  # in this case for deletion
        if ($stream) { $stream.Close() }
        return $false
    }
    catch {
        return $true
    }
}
```

Now if I open a file in MS Word, and test that file

```
Test-LockedFile 'D:\Test\blah.rtf'
```

returns `True`

When I open the same file in Wordpad, the test results in `False`.

Another way to determine if a file is locked, although sneaky is to try and change the extension (or any file attribute for that matter) of that file. If opened in a locking application, you can't do that, but when opened in Wordpad, no problem..

Comment: Ha! To see if a file is locked, try to lock it. SO OBVIOUS, in hindsight. :)